# How to make arduino pin high and low for specific time from android

Tags: android, arduino

I am making android application which sends signal from android app to arduino.
But i want to make arduino pin high and low for specific time period say one hour.
i.e user will specify the time period and length of time period..
How i can approach in android for this..

Comment: I have made a simple application which make arduino pin high and low over ethernet..I have read about alarmmanager class etc in android but dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

For Android you need to schedule your background task at regular interval as a separate process. You can use [Syncadapter](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/2d52182dfac91014c2975a1bb1afd99a3b14b4e9/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/syncadapter/SyncAdapter.java) for your android application.

or Try this

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                try{
                    //do your Arduino code here
                    //also call the same runnable 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                finally{
                    //also call the same Arduino code here
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
                }
            } 
        }; 
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
```

Hope it helps !